# symbolicatecrash location in XCode 5

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode5

Using Xcode 5 I noticed that the symbolicatecrash.sh executable is no more available under the old location:

*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash*

Anybody knows where I can find it? Maybe there is a newest integrated way to symbolicate crash reports?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

New location under XCode5:

*Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash*

Comment: New location in Xcode 6 is: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`

Comment: Not able to find 'symbolicatecrash' inside `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Ver‌​sions/A/Resources/`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it turned out to be in SharedFrameworks:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecras
```

Anyway, from your Xcode.app path, just run:

```
find . -name "symbolicatecrash"
```